# How to create realism similar to scenes rendered in Vray?

Tags: rendering, unity, lighting, 3dsmax

I am tasked to make a game which requires very realistic interior scenes. Unity's bedroom demo(http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/11/10/bedroom-demo-archviz-with-ssrr/) really caught my eye. See I know how to code but I am not good at modelling in 3DS. I see some amazing images only generated in 3DS using vray. But those are static images and the moment the same models are imported into Unity, they end up looking unrealistic. But somehow in the demo, Unity managed to create a very realistic looking scene. So here are my questions :

- How do I create realistic game scenes like the ones rendered by vray in 3DS Max? Is it possible to bake the image rendered by vray into a UV map? I couldnt find how to do this.
- Also, pls refer to the image in this link, from evermotion http://www.evermotion.org/files/tutorials_content/uploads/nr_AI44_002_cam_001_pp_051.jpg and also this image : http://www.evermotion.org/files/tutorials_content/uploads/nr_ae44s02__0041_Layer_2_022.jpg. The second pic is very unrealistic but the first pic after vray rendering looks amazing. I am sure the bedroom demo assets looked the same and assuming the answer to my first question is it cannot be done, then how do I go about creating the same level of realism as in the first pic?

Guys this is a really long question and might not be clear. So sorry, tried to describe it the best I can. Appreciate any answer, tips or advice. Thanks guys

Comment: Raycasting is a completely different rendering approach than the scanline-based engine of Unity. So you will never achieve the exact same results with these two techniques. However, Unity also has some nice tricks up its sleeve to make scenes look better. But describing them all would be far too broad for the format of this website.

Comment: The Unity blog you link already provides the basic recipe: high quality assets with physically-based materials, a good lighting setup with an HDR cubemap, and [light probes](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightProbes.html) to approximate realtime global illumination. (If you're not using dynamic objects/lights in your scene, you may be able to bake the lighting statically instead)

Comment: Btw, who gave you the task to (probably alone) make a game, wich competes with ray casting's quality? A game should be a game, not real life.

Comment: @Balint actually its just a prototype with only a small level. I would agree its pretty unrealistic to build a game with ray casting quality alone. You said a game should be a game and not real life. But isn't everyone trying to make games that are ultra realistic, almost real life? I mean I havent seen a game that looks 100% real but its close or there maybe some elements in the game world that does actually look real. I have always felt that hardware is the only stumbling block for everyone, a problem I believe will be solved eventually.

Comment: @Kumaresan Sandran If it's just a small level, then spending a lot of money on it would be insane. But yes, the fact, that you have a small scene makes some things easier, for example if you need dynamic shadow mapping, then ypu can get away with a smaller shadow map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the realism provided by ray casting engines (e.g. vray) without a ray casting. You can only get very close to it.

Ray casting is a **simulation**, xou simulate how lightrays bounce off from objects. Hardware rendering is not a simulation. You can get close to it, but most of the times, it requires you to re-render the scene multiple times in different position, for exampls shadow mapping.

Comment: well that makes sense. i guess i am gonna have to rely on high quality assets and textures as well as a good lighting system.